# searching in advance custom field (wp rest api)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have last wordpress and  some fields (acf)  in my custom post type.I use this address to search

```
  mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/jozve?search=....
```

but it searched in content and title.how can i search in **fields** with rest-api?
i install `Search Everything & ACF: Better Search plugin` but it didnt work.